# how to update a table based on previous entries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am having a serious trouble using triggers in mysql.
Basically I am trying to update a row `on after insert`. I am using the existing value in the row and trying to update an other column of same row.

Ex:

```
Existing_Name Actual_Name
Product_Arc1  Arc1
Product_Arc2  Arc2
Product_Arc3
```

I am taking the value of `Existing_Name` and extracting the second part of it and updating the `Actual_Name` using triggers. BUt since MySQL does not support updating the same table the trigger was activated on? is there any possible way to do what I want?

As of now, I am using PHP script to perform the same effect. But this requires the end user to keep triggering this script from the web browser whenever there are some changes in the database.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an "one **after** insert" trigger? This would be the case if you needed an auto_increment value to calculate the value of the field you want to modify. Otherwise a "before insert" trigger should do. You can change values of fields to be inserted via `SET NEW.fieldname = newvalue`

E.g. let's take the table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int auto_increment, x int, y int, primary key(id))
```

and [create a before insert trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER footrigger BEFORE INSERT ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.y > NEW.x THEN
       SET NEW.y = -1;
    END IF;
  END;
|
```

And now let's insert two records, one where y=x and one where y>x

```
INSERT INTO foo (x,y) VALUES (1,1), (1,2)
```

A `SELECT x,y FROM foo` then returns

```
"x";"y"
"1";"1"
"1";"-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you directly change the insert mechanism?
insert into table(Existing_Name,Actual_Name) values ($Existing_Name, replace($Existing_Name,'Product_','')...

Comment: I dont' understand what you mean. Can you please detail me? Where exactly do you think I need to place this code? after insert?

Comment: This was not for trigger. Instead of creating a trigger, original insert query can be edited like this.

Comment: ok, can you please show me the correct full insert like the above please?